# How to add form to access page number in instant search?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I used this script (https://www.webslesson.info/2020/02/instant-search-with-pagination-in-php-mysql-jquery-and-ajax.html) and I would like to add a form to directly access a page number.

I tried this but it doesn't work !

```
<div class="goto-page">
<form action="" method="POST"  onsubmit="return pageValidation()">
<input type="submit" class="goto-button" value="Go to page">
<input type="text"
class="enter-page-no" maxlength="4" size="3"
name="goto" min="1"
required >
</form>
</div>
```

PHP Code modified

```
if (isset($_POST['goto'])) {
    $start = (($_POST['page'] - 1) * $limit);
    $page = $_POST['goto'];
    } 
    else 
    {
    if($_POST['page'] > 1)
    {
        $start = (($_POST['page'] - 1) * $limit);
        $page = $_POST['page'];
    }
    else
    {
    $start = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looking at your link, you would simply want to use `load_data()`. You will want to capture the Text Field Value and pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example. This expands on the jQuery already in use in the example you linked to.

```js
$(function() {
  function load_data(page, query = '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: "fetch.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        page: page,
        query: query
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
      }
    });
  }

  load_data(1);

  $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function() {
    var page = $(this).data('page_number');
    var query = $('#search_box').val();
    load_data(page, query);
  });

  $('#search_box').keyup(function() {
    var query = $('#search_box').val();
    load_data(1, query);
  });

  $(".goto-page form").submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    load_data(parseInt($(".goto-page input[name='goto']").val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br />
<div class="container">
  <h3 align="center">Live Data Search with Pagination in PHP Mysql using Ajax</h3>
  <br />
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Dynamic Data</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="search_box" id="search_box" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your search query here" />
      </div>
      <div class="table-responsive" id="dynamic_content">
      </div>
      <div class="goto-page">
        <form>
          <button type="submit">Go To Page</button>
          <input type="text" class="enter-page-no" maxlength="4" size="3" name="goto" value="1" required>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit or the Button pressed, the form is submitted. The `submit` callback will gather the value and use `load_data()` to load that page.

Comment: Thanks, Perfect it works !
At the beginning no because I had put the code of the form in the fetch.php.